# Merge a Premiere-Elements project into another project

Tags: premiere-elements

I want to create reusable video projects and merge them with other projects. For example - create an ending with a copyright notice, a website url, and some more information, and then use that as the ending for multiple videos.

Of course this can be done by simply merging the video *output* (as I've seen suggested on several threads), but that would reduce the quality. Is there any way to merge a project into another project so as to preserve the quality?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that can be done in Premiere Elements. In Premiere Pro, you can import sequences from other projects, which would accomplish what you're asking for, but as far as I know, you can't do that in Premiere Elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can render the ending with a lossless format (e.g. Animation/PNG) and then just append that to all your other videos.

Answer (score -1):

I've done this your way... ...Trying to recreate video from assets is like trying to run through a line at the DMV or an IRS counter, and it's always audit season, or two days after the day with the most births 16 years ago (kids drive at 16 here).

Here's what I did to stop that:

1. Create a project with all my most reused content and save that in a file.  Lock this file as READ ONLY.  You can unlock it when you want to make changes.
2. When you are building the rest of your content, start from the read only, then save as... ...and build a file for your new project from that.
3. For less used content, get a large RAID storage with rapid access, and a BDXL burner.  Store your content in fullest format on the RAID, then burn it to the BDXL in file mode, and burn 3 of them.  Put them in plastic out of the sunlight, in a temp-controlled safe or file cabinet area, with a sticker label on the case only.  When you need the data again, RAID will do for a storage block.  Older RAID will work ok for 720 video speeds, but newer with even cheap ssd will work far better for the larger video and frame\data rates.
4. Keep the most used data and a copy of the project template it goes with together wherever you place them.  Personally, I have a drive hooked to a router, that houses a templates and folders for audio only, video only, or both.  The files kept here are the lower quality proxies.  They correspond by filename to the larger quality videos I keep on BDXL.